# What is: A curly brace enclosure with a first variable name then a colon which separates the same variable name again? {name:name}

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

This possibly relates to Javascript, TypeScript, or Angular 2.  I'm not sure?

Here is an example:

```
onSearch( term:string) 
{
    this.router.navigate([' search', {term: term}]);
}
```

I don't understand what the '{term: term}' is doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the parameters are passed via the navigate Method. It accepts object, where
term is the variable name and other term is the string that needs to be passed. It would be more appropriate if you write.

```
this.router.navigate([' search', {'term': term}]);
```

Comment: The lack of quotations around the 'term' was throwing me off.  Thank you.